# F# plotting datetime issues

Tags: charts, plot, f#

I have a collection that is in format datetimeoffset - option int64.
I would like to plot a line from this data.

I tried with with just piping my data to Chart.Line:

`Chart.Line(data |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.time.DateTime, r.input.Value))` but i got following output.

[image]

Now I know my data doesn't look like this. At least I tried running:

```
data |> Array.map (fun r -> r.Timestamp.DateTime) |> Array.min
data |> Array.map (fun r -> r.Timestamp.DateTime) |> Array.max
```

And got

```
DateTime = 10/29/2014 6:30:15 PM
DateTime = 10/30/2014 6:00:15 PM
```

So I don't have any data near the beginning of the previous century.

When I plot by DateTime.Ticks instead of datetime data looks as it should be looking:

[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You need to set the range on your time axis, I guess. Clearly your charting library doesn't cope with DateTimes well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot, I suppose you're using the F# Charting library.

I did a quick test using the latest version and it seems to be handling `DateTimeOffset` correctly as the key, but `DateTime` incorrectly! Given the following setup:

```
#load "packages/FSharp.Charting.0.90.7/FSharp.Charting.fsx"
open FSharp.Charting
open System
```

The following works fine:

```
[ for i in 0 .. 100 do 
    yield DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(float i)), int64 i ]
|> Chart.Line
```

But the following behaves similarly to your snippet:

```
[ for i in 0 .. 100 do 
    yield DateTime.Now.AddHours(float i), int64 i ]
|> Chart.Line
```

So the workaround for you should be to just return `r.time` rather than getting `DateTime`:

```
Chart.Line(data |> Seq.map (fun r -> r.time, r.input.Value))
```

This seems to be a bug! Please submit an issue [on the project GitHub page](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Charting).

**EDIT** Figured it out - there is a difference between how `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` behave.

Comment: Hm, I am getting same output with DateTimeOffset as well. Took a glance at source code as saw this line: /// Register a function that is used to automatically transform X values (keys) 
        /// of a non-primitive type to one of the types supported by the charting library
        /// (for example, by default DateTimeOffset is converted to DateTime)

Comment: That's odd - can you try running my two code snippets to see if you can reproduce my results?

Comment: Updating the FSharp.Chart to 0.90.7 solved the problem (for datetime offset). With 0.90.6 I still have the same issue. Thanks!